# Laplace of the square root of trig functions?

Tags: trigonometry, laplace-transform

I want to find the laplace of 1/rootcos(t)

Laplace calculators don't give an answer with this as an input. I know nothing about laplace, so can someone explain why this happens? Is it impossible to perform laplace on square roots? I'm assuming there's nothing wrong with the calculators.

Comment: 1. Do you mean Laplace transform? 

2. $\sqrt{\cos t}$ isn't uniquely defined if $\cos t<0$. Which of the complex roots you take?

3. It's possible that Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos t}}$ just doesn't express in terms of other named functions. It doesn't mean it's impossible to perform it, it would just mean that it is its own function with no know relation to other named functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want a nice formula (given by a CAS, be sure !)
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(t)}}\right](s)=\Gamma \left(\frac{2i s+1}{4}\right) \left(i \,
   _2\tilde{F}_1\left(1,\frac{2 i s+3}{4} ;\frac{2 i s+3}{4} ;-1\right)+\frac{\left(1-i\right) \sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{3
   \pi  s}{2}} (\coth (\pi  s)-1)}{2\,\Gamma \left(\frac{2i
   s+3}{4}\right)}\right)$$

Comment: Nice one Claude